# Why do I get these warnings for my Vega specification?

Tags: warnings, vega

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhDIATgGsIaANqhMATxxw0IMnLYMc0kHHFQ2AEx2pQRy0kw3QAdxqX6aUBBplxSABtdTCQ5MjhMAH14XywAAgAqOIAmAEZKAAYATgBmAHYAFgAOQuS81IKBZIKQAF8ZGLIsLxAfP0Dg0PCoxvikjMo8nIFh1IFUooA2SazJnNScupkcJEtLGnEyFrb-IPRgALgAM0xUOPOQsIjouFjMRLiBjIy8otTqrKyRgpyckoWpHE5HcznFLt0bncHk8Xm8Pl8cj8-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-KI3AAASukyVOckpQVMJFAIRRU3Zvzlv2xQRgaYNSHGU3oIJyamIt6YeljknuNJ5GcwZYUKQSkW+dMWnJMiiyRk2HP6W2pM62y-YLBpDPDMkyQlG8DmuhO5suYcbkLvld7snRp7-sFe6hfJqUByeT4oglmJJX7xnHr+DHnmjb4MlbEdJ4+f4UoBMjAYqcPgVK7UNUXTUtRqHpgUhKGGiA6F9dhA02kNDpOssjkexrFsJ0eP45ynJsyMxDCsexo2KONYOS9LCYGEJC1pmJOAOBJHpSXmvetv3SS05QBSVPM7xvDkml1jpdzOST2sR+UWS9rbg7ZCMI6RmOTme9OrnzmH3P+2zvRM8lJdxYH3JnHmkdk4gNjlePegZB7AODjldOyVlyAKQUHPOlUQJbUlHVXBFc4KtRrjVVAnV9QNybphfqVo252g7sRd2ZFPSa0tnfKBQDsGMUjGPCeaAOIyC4uNeeAlF7yxEkrOwa8syq1zDfLmGDWQHzrAUe2zschO2spFK+LJFFa3Dlw0yWiLK5CsjZPIdk3akQMTOb2f90FGSPOlaKmVSrlRDuA-+yiXF6zcf5OKZUgoXjjr7SBgDXHFXcUEzxqC6QZ04ZE-x0TAmBXzgKPBZD4alyggXKqld4LZPApQ7qjdeq0JbvQvCw0nRT24hNfiRZZrzQVivZauM4BrQ9BtLCoBa6qD2gdI6MMzqYGBldG6d14BQAUD9LU7h1RxDYEcF65gYAiJAJLKUkNoaw3wboZmqNXx0gxiAFWHocb40JnYhB5MfhDGpuVWmJIGZM1hmza+38lHOO-HzAWmVhYaTUvZVCtQ558RlnoCRwlFar3XtmNW282F9wiSogYZVZhTGdk7L4Qwaim3ZjvW+Rj-Z2XKpFBmqRpgZCNiPEAn8e4oq9nOdyaKB7KR4eeMBf87nQKHrA0J8D2Xfk5dHVOJy8oisQWK3OvIiHCgORBMu+TGokOrv08hpTqEVL6VKVuNSmFdxYbc6VtEo5yvDA3TZPFZ7gvqGI2WMLl5LWVrIjergkWmqSSo9IP5Kzn0qEULSejmjfMMQAxOcUKjBtMdTAQWQtLv2NbY8N9jWXhJ9X4oqnwYnZR5RArNq4om5rScEuB8czUmRSaWrK5b4lSqLYVDKZauoKuLgQlVmTiHNSKZq+G2q0K6roYNRhhFO4Mu7qw4mPyybVpzSVWJAgmJsBYmxQR9TRGQoXkmWF7S3UIvkerZlJLI0PDSJkIqJQj5KXKNpQlXziWzutk8XFJI0hDCKGkesj8bFfyffsBxbKm3mpgSggtPjfkysDuKyk6IwmQbndw2DgI04JKcUhrBsGMmF0VcUzteTu2wV7aQ-tJTkJdR1RhPVOEGH4SYZu2M27pqbRddIhWq0LS7OZkqxusNjnowbhc9QLSlU7QAEpwH+lAcZz02BMChnIUglhPrfWepYBgchzoSAgBeME8AgRIE2HAOIKgAAagIACaINKBbMjFcgmJ0iayQjb44tLwlI3s0q8OyQxl1oQ+USk9z6s4VG5H2DIUw-gfFBahCFk0d1Lzaa6mRh7N5erTQgi9GkYuFEqNG+9DQgsztc1Bp4QasixtsmVHInwCUpv-cFwDGbEMvv5cg58EGMNteQ5auDiVM2ksTlhvrqHJWJKGxymDfWcNVV44Q8uxGq5KsHT1ajI66O1P5DaxpULel7pSxxrp61RP4cGQASTYoKBgMmJkAAprq3TRjAX6UmFDwbiEZlTCB5M0EOHEKGmAjAQAAJToBkAABSM3EQiP0kBxBwGwDYsmyCveIDQKAJm7uHVgJ93T8OfuETgCDqkGg4gOORlAGGsy4fWl+lpsgtBnqBAkKj+gJmYA3VOhIEIARfo0DkHAW7EgTAAC02B0hhz4ZnCOke4x+tYdHmPScA6gAYAIiNUd3dIHIcZUBAiq-VwEEHJgofiCl3DuICAGABHGeiG7L2Ng4EwmjjHWOccvchp9i8DvoCC7MCTpgZPLAM6Z6jtw9BllIyum6Lpn2Ais-0xzrnJ0ecG-WIL4XkgZDi8l7DmX1vbd0EMLjp3LvFdu5VzgDYsAfoR5e5gFwbAY-GbkPjhPz12dxE58CVPuN08C6F+MkX2yIZQx42dhG-G0MIDOcJ-CPPHPOfYXy2lYwY303MkpSshW+NI0+fozLVbaVTCmFUVIvYrEbkmOLe1s9R4SCOL4FoctthzeVbKVVPblsUIo-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)

The Vega Editor produces very strange warnings for my Vega spec (see them with ALT+F8).

1. In a mark, it highlights `"type": "text"` and says 'Value is not accepted. Valid values: "group".'
2. In `encode`, it highlights `"baseline": {"value": "line-bottom"}` and says 'Value is not accepted. Valid values: "top", "middle", "bottom", "alphabetic".'

The `line-top` and `line-bottom` baselines were added in 5.10 according to https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a validation bug. line-bottom is causing the other errors. If you change it to bottom they go away. I'll raise a bug on github.

Comment: Do you know whether this affects the rendering of my visualization, or is it just harmless warnings then? I guess it's just harmless warnings.

Comment: It is a harmless warning. Your visualisation is complex and has a lot of contradictory encodings in there which is why it isn't displaying much. I suggest paring it back and building it up in pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The Vega editor warnings about "line-bottom" is because [Vega schema definition](https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json) has not been updated properly to match [Vega documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/text/) for text "baseline" to include "line-top" and "line-bottom".

[image]